# How to prove that the fields' contribution to the action in Feynman's Path Integral are quantized?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, path-integral, discrete

The Lagrangian density in the path integral contains spinor, vector and number fields. However, their combinations in the action are scalars such as $\bar \psi \psi$, just numbers. Let's say I have an electron at time $t$ and position $x$, why can't I change the value of the fields so that $\bar \psi \psi$ is only half its original value, thereby creating half an electron? This is even more of a bother with a scalar field like the Higgs which I just think of as a number to begin with.

If I CAN make the suggested change, is it true that only external particles are quantized?

Comment: I think I don't fully understand the question. For scalar fields, the action converts functions (the Lagrangian with a number-valued field) to numbers via integration over spacetime. The path integral then integrates over different choices of the number-valued field. This underlies a variety of discretization procedures for numerical evaluation of path integrals.

Comment: Looks like I didn't ask the right question. What I meant is: Take an equal-time hypersurface according to some observer. If you integrate $\bar \psi \psi$ over that hypersurface, you have to get an integer. That is because it multiplies the mass and if it wasn't an integer, you would have fractional numbers of particles, violating second quantization. However, while we know this is true because Feynman Path Integration and Second Quantization are the same thing, it's not explicitly stated and so I'm wondering if it's true for virtual particles or if it may only be true for real particles.

Comment: This question does not make sense - the value of the integral of some expression in the fields is an *operator* in QFT, not a number, and especially not some number of particles.

Comment: @ACuriousMind That is incorrect. It is an operator according to the operator formalism developed by Tomonaga and Schwinger but a (c- or Grassmann) number in Feynman's formalism. Their equivalence was shown by Dyson in 1948 but it took a while before he was believed.

Comment: Even in the path integral formalism, there's no definite value for the fields. There's still just expectation values, or the integration over all possible field configurations inside the path integral, while your question seems to presuppose some definite value of the integral of $\bar \psi\psi$ attached to some state of reality. This just isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

The Lagrangian density in the Feynman integral contains complex (for Bosons) or Grassmann number (for Fermions) fields, not operators. This is possible as in the time slicing construction you can show that the contribution of the commutators (anti-commutators) to the intergal goes to zero as the time slice length goes to zero. (Well at least physics-rigorously.) That you can have a formulation of quantum evolution in terms of commuting / anti-commuting numbers is essential to the power of the Feynman path integral as computational device.

This has not really anything to do with particles being quantized or not. Roughly quantization shows when measuring, while the path-integral gives an expression for the propagator that describes the linear, time continuous evolution of the state.

Comment: I don't this is completely correct. For Grassmann variables in the Feynman formalism, you can show that the contribution of each space-time point to the path integral from the mass term alone is -m, the -1 coming from the $det(\gamma_0)$. This can be understood as the sum of nothing and m (the -1 is because it's a Fermion) with the interpretation that you either have a particle there or you don't, there is no in-between.

Comment: Hmm, I'd be interested to see a demonstration of that. In the end certain consequences of the quantization must show up in the path integral expressions as well (e.g. as you can compute observable things like densities from the propagators and those show certain quantization), and also because it is in a way a rewriting for the vacuum expectation values. As I remember it the action path integral (at least for bosons) can't be evaluated – it contains a divergent factor that cancels in the expressions for the propagators, so it can't be the place where the quantization shows up manifestly.

Comment: (And I fully admit my second paragraph was quite hand-waving, it was more of a try to convey the message that you don't need to look at the quantization at the level of the action – the maths tells you that the path integral expressions give you the quantum expectation values, so quantization of particle number must be "somewhere in there").

Comment: Indeed, after checking I realized it is the sum of $(-\frac{i m a^4}{\hbar} - 1)$ and $1$ for the case that there is a particle there or no particle there. The $a^4$ here is a small volume factor that eventually cancels when you take infinitely dense space-time points - after renormalization, of course. That volume factor together with the fact that electrons are often found spread-out in space makes me think that I was in error in what I said. In other words, it seems like Feynman's sum of histories allows for fractional virtual particles that also don't have to conserve momentum or spin.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to speak about a virtual particle being there or not (partially or whole). They are, in a sense, just an artefact of the mathematics of the perturbation expansion, and in the perturbation terms they are either there or not. But yes, even the propagator for a real particle contains terms for paths that break momentum or spin conservation in the "sum of histories"-approach, but the contribution from those cancel out in the propagator (up to effects that can be understood in terms of the uncertainty relation).